# Can we deduce that particles behave as Brownian motions if the collection obeys the Einstein model?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, mathematical-physics, diffusion, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

The density dynamics of a continuum of particles with the dynamics $$dx^i_s = d w^i_s,$$ where $dw^i_s$, $0 \leq s$, $i \in \mathcal{N}$ is a standard Brownian motion, are given by the diffusion PDE $$\partial_t p = \nabla^2 p,$$ where $p(s,x)$ is the density of the particles $(x^i_s)_{i \in \mathcal{N}}$ for all $0 \leq s$. Is the inverse true?

In other words, if the density dynamics are given by the diffusion PDE, then, does that imply that the particle dynamics are Brownian (or is it possible to have some other dynamics governing the identical patricles, which result in the same density dynamics)? An analogous question naturally arises in the case of general [Langevin dynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langevin_dynamics) as well.

Comment: Are you asking whether an SDE and the Fokker-Planck equation are equivalent? Yes, but if you want to know all the detail and technical conditions, I suspect you're going to have better luck getting answers at the Maths SE.

Comment: You're on point @alarge. I know that the SDE has an equivalent representation in terms of the density dynamics of the stochastic process as the Fokker-Planck equation. The question remains whether, given a Fokker-Planck equation, there are multiple SDEs associated with it. The most relevant literature on this topic comes from the [physics literature](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.150.1079) which is why I have posed this question here.